# If I farm, I'm a farmer. But if I guard, I'm a guard?

Tags: etymology, verbs, nouns

One who farms is called a farmer.

One who waits is called a waiter.

One who dives is called a diver.

One who programs is called a programmer.

But one who guards is called a guard.

**How did it come to be that this word dropped its -er ending for its noun, and are there other examples like it, sharing any commonalities?**

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/guarder) lists guarder as a noun, implying that it can be used instead of guard (and has an example sentence). But from my experience as a native American-English speaker, I can't recall it ever being used outside of poetic-style writing. Both dictionary.com and merriam-webster list guard as coming from the Old-French guarder, but I'm not sure why this word was special and dropped the -er.

Comment: In fairness, you might be _guardian_ (if you're guarding a ward) or a _warden_ (if you're guarding prisoners). Not that that helps.

Comment: Judge not judger is another example.

Comment: I am reading their etymology on Wiktionary and it mentions alternative forms and derived terms. But I see both guardian and guard comes from Old French *guardian, gardein, garden, *gardenc, from the verb guarder, of Germanic origin. What a mess really. I am so sleepy in the morning cannot make any sense of anything. I suggest check both pages and all those French and Germanic words related. You might be able to connect the pieces which I could not.

Comment: The Old French word *guarder* (modern French *garder*) meant *to guard*. The Old French word for *one who guards* was *guardian* (modern French *gardien*). The *-er* was never dropped.

Comment: There are other suffixes besides *-er/-or* indicating agency; one who *types* is a *typist*, one who *occupies* is an *occupant*, and one who *politics* is a *politician*, and then there are the various (mostly obsolete) suffixes for female agents, producing the likes of *aviatrix* and *authoress*.

Comment: It's English.  Words adopted from a dozen different languages, at many different times, and merged with other words or conventions.

Comment: For that matter, both 'guard' and 'ward' come from Old French 'garder'.  (This is a fairly standard development: cf. guarantee and warranty, Guillaume and William, etc.)

Comment: And butchers butcher, tinkers tinker, and tailors tailor.  English is weird.

Comment: Did someone tell you English is simple? Because it isn't. Well done for noticing the pattern and the exceptions.

Comment: @SvenYargs Or gaoler (or jailer). Both have the -er suffix to appease OP. ;-)

Comment: For an almost direct equivalent that follows the rules one who protects is a protector

Comment: Even more confusingly, if you scamper are you a scamp?

Comment: And there are others: pilot,  soldier, spy, engineer, and I'm sure there are more.

Comment: If you like walk dogs you're definitely a dogger! 

Comment: @ArcanistLupus Tinkers tinker, tailors tailor, soliders soldier, spies spy! [Le Carre's list of examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinker_Tailor_Soldier_Spy) was presumably a coincidence. Tinker is of uncertain origin (But the verb came later than the noun/surname); the others all seem to come from French.

Comment: There's also the fact that the Agentive _-er_ is identical in form to the Comparative _-er_. One goes on (some) verbs to form agentive nouns, and the other goes on (some) adjectives to form comparative adjectives. Comparative is an [inflectional suffix](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf), whereas Agentive is derivational. They have different phonology, though -- the comparative of _long_ (adj) is _longer_ /'lɔŋɡəɹ/, with a /ɡ/ following the /ŋ/, whereas the agentive noun _longer_ 'one who longs' is pronounced /'lɔŋəɹ/, with no /ɡ/. They don't rhyme, though they're spelt identically.

Comment: Even more confusing with similar words cross-language - a german will wonder why it isn't "murd" and "murder" instead of "murder" and "murderer" :)

Comment: Heh heh. Once during a game of Scrabble, I tried to use the following argument.  Lug, luggage. Groom, groommage. It was not allowed.

Comment: And what does a prisoner do???

Comment: @Aconcagua Moulder?

Answer (score 94):

You can't drop what you never had. *Guard* (noun) according to the Oxford English Dictionary comes from:

> French *garde*, earlier also *guarde* (= Italian *guarda*, Spanish *guarda*) < Romance **guarda*, < Old Germanic **wardâ*.

**The noun "guard" predates the verb** in English. The verb *to guard* comes either from the noun or from the same French word the noun comes from. For some reason, as you note, there is a word *guarder* (formed from *guard* (verb) + *er*) that came into being after both the noun and verb forms of *guard* (which looks like it was a lot more popular some hundreds of years ago, but isn't really used now).

---

Interestingly enough some of your examples aren't really examples. *Farmer*, for example, wasn't originally formed from the English words *farm* + *er*. The OED lists its etymology as:

> Anglo-Norman *fermer* (Britton), French *fermier* < medieval Latin *firmārius*, < *firma* : see farm n.2 Now usually apprehended as agent-noun < *farm* v.2 + -*er* suffix1; some modern uses may be properly regarded as belonging to this formation and not to the older word.
>
> <sub>In the early recorded forms the suffix -*er* has been replaced by -*our*, so that the word apparently corresponds to the synonymous medieval Latin *firmātor*, one who takes something on lease (Du Cange), agent-noun < *firmāre* in sense to contract for, become responsible for.</sub>

Similarly, *waiter* wasn't formed in English originally according to the OED:

> Originally < Anglo-Norman **waitour*, Old French *weitteor*, *gaiteor*, agent-noun < *weitier*, *gaitier* wait v.1 In later use < *wait* v.1 + -*er* suffix1.

Comment: +1 Interesting answer. Do you happen to have a source saying that the noun predates the verb in French? Or did you mean in English? // One other minor point: you say *water* has a similar etymology, but I see it has the suffix *-er* rather than *-arius*? // Lastly, it isn't entirely clear to me what the OED means when it says *"so that the word apparently corresponds to the synonymous medieval Latin firmātor"*: what do you think they mean by "correspond", exactly? Does it still come from *firmarius*, or does it have a mixed origin? But perhaps we should ask the editors of the dictionary.

Comment: Beat me to the punch; this is also why one who *soldiers* is a *soldier*, not to mention more general examples where the noun and verb meanings are divergent (e.g. *lord*, *dwarf*).

Comment: @Cerberus It's the English noun "guard" that predates the English verb, and the source is the OED. // For *waiter*: I mean they were both formed outside of English. // For *farmer*: I'm not really sure either. It looks to me like there was some confusion and they mixed up the first half of the one with the ending of the other to get "[fermour](https://books.google.com/books?id=BkwzAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA361&lpg=PA361&dq=%22As+is+a+fermour%22)" but then later people spelled it like "fermer".

Comment: @choster - Sorry, but you got tripped up on dwarf. The verb "to dwarf" means "to be much larger than", so a dwarf does not dwarf.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Of course not: a dwarf dwarves, doncha know. :)

Comment: @whatroughbeast My point was that there are multiple patterns which are not always predictable. A wolf wolfs, but a dog does not dog; the floats float and the nets net, but the fish do not fish and the crabs do not crab.

Comment: @choster actually crabs do crab.  The act of walking sideways as crabs do is crabbing or 'to crab'.  Also used in aviation to denote a plane flying sideways.  For ref see:  https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/crab

Comment: @choster Dogs do dog. My spaniel followed me from room to room, often so closely that we considered renaming him "Trip Hazard".

Answer (score 39):

How about these, examples of professions that are both verb and noun where the verb expresses the work that the person typically does:

- guard
- coach
- cook
- guide
- host
- judge
- nurse
- pimp
- scout
- smith
- spy
- whore

As to the etymology of *guard*, [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/guard#etymonline_v_14338) says the follwing:

> from Middle French ***garde*** "guardian, warden, keeper; watching, keeping, custody," from Old French *garder* "to keep, maintain, preserve, protect"

So I presume *garde* first had an abstract meaning, more like "the phaenomenon of guarding", and as in "be on your guard! en garde!" or "my guard" denoting the body of men that guard me; and then it also came to be used for a person doing guarding later.

It appears that English only dropped the *-e* from the French profession after borrowing the noun. Since *-e* is unstressed and often mute or even silent in French, it isn't very surprising that it should have fallen off. In fact, there are countless nouns in older English that dropped an *-e*. Cf. the (probably anistorical) trope *ye olde [noun]*.

Comment: One who cooks is a cooker... I like that.

Comment: @GEdgar: Well, or a cook?

Comment: For "Pimp" we do have "Whoremonger" as a -er form of the action, but the base of the noun isn't exactly descriptive of the verb either.

Comment: Matching the etymology:  You can say "you guard something", or you can say "you stand [as a] guard over something"- this seems more like the verb "to guard" came *from* the noun "a Guard", as opposed to the other way around.

Comment: Also: one who _doctors_ is a  _doctor_, one who _bitches_ is a _bitch_, one who _thieves_ is a _thief_, one who _cheats_ is a _cheat_, one who _jockeys_ is a _jockey_, one who _teases_ is a _tease_, there are many, many examples of this sort of thing.

Comment: @GEdgar actually, the 'cooker' is a perfect example for '-er' indicating agency in general and not necessarily a (human) profession. Think 'blender', 'cash dispenser', 'lawn mower' etc.

Comment: What an odd head-cannon, whorer!

Comment: @terdon, one who cheats is also a *cheater*, which according to etymonline.com is attested as meaning *dishonest player* in the 1530s, whereas *cheat* in that sense is not attested before the 1660s.

Comment: @PeterTaylor oh absolutely, and one who teases can also be a teaser. I was just giving a few more examples.

Comment: Oh, the whorer, the whorer!

Comment: They can all be used as verbs?

Comment: See also the original meaning of 'computer', as in someone who computes. The current sense of the word is modern.

Comment: @BCLC: Yes, and they express the kind of work the noun is typically doing.

Answer (score 17):

With 'er' 'or' 'ist' suffixes you are usually dealing with an [agent noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_noun)

From the Wikipedia link:

> In linguistics, an agent noun (in Latin, nomen agentis) is a word that
>   is derived from another word denoting an action, and that identifies
>   an entity that does that action. For example, "driver" is an agent
>   noun formed from the verb "drive".

So with agent nouns the verb comes first and the noun arises later. But in your example it's actually the other way round. The verb [guard](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/guard?s=t) is derived from the noun. ([Alternatively](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=guard) it was derived separately from the old French, but later chronologically, which would still explain why it doesn't fit the standard pattern.)

From the [online etymology dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/guard#etymonline_v_14338)

> **guard (n.)**
>
> **early 15c**., "one who keeps watch, a body of soldiers," also "care,
>   custody, guardianship," and the name of a part of a piece of armor,
>   from Middle French garde "guardian, warden, keeper; watching, keeping,
>   custody," from Old French garder "to keep, maintain, preserve,
>   protect" (see guard (v.)).
>
> **guard (v.)**
>
> **mid-15c.**, **from guard (n.)** or from Old French garder "to keep watch over, guard, protect, maintain, preserve" (corresponding to Old North
>   French warder, see gu-), from Frankish *wardon, from Proto-Germanic
>   *wardon "to guard" (from PIE root *wer- (3) "perceive, watch out for"). Italian guardare, Spanish guardar also are from Germanic.
>   Related: Guarded; guarding.

Such a conversion process is seen by some linguists as a form of **metonymy**.

There's a very detailed article [here](http://www.academia.edu/5377771/The_interaction_of_metaphor_and_metonymy_in_noun-to-verb_conversion) from which I'll also lift their definition:

> [Metonymy](http://www.academia.edu/5377771/The_interaction_of_metaphor_and_metonymy_in_noun-to-verb_conversion)
>   is a cognitive process in which one conceptual entity" the vehicle"
>   provides mental access to another conceptual entity" the target"
>   within the same idealized cognitive models (Radden and Kovecses 1999,
>   p.21).

In your case the noun denoting the agent of the action -- the guard -- is employed to denote the action itself. So 'guard' comes to mean what a guard does. A parallel example (from the above linked article) would be the noun father becoming the verb father as in 'he fathers several children'.

Comment: I don’t really think zero-derivation in English can be considered metonymy. It’s just that the old derivational suffixes which used to be employed disappeared over time when final syllables were lost due to apocope. Earlier on, the derivation would have been more overt.

Comment: Yes, it's not universally accepted. I've slightly changed the wording to reflect this. (And in the meantime plan to work out whose side I'm on.)

Answer (score 2):

Many *-er* words for people do indeed derive from some other word such as a verb but many do not. The use of *-r* for people is extremely widespread in Indo-European languages but some of the most common clearly show that they are not just agents, but any kind of people, often not being derived from any other identifiable word: think of *mother*, *father*, *brother*, *sister*, *daughter*, with the first four of these at least clearly going back to Proto-Indo-European.

Across many languages we see a great variety in the vowel before the *-r*, which is why we have *entrepreneur* (from French), *doctor* (from Latin), *scholar* (from Latin). Other languages are even more varied. Consider *mère* (French for "mother"), *sœur* (French for "sister"), *feirmeoir* (Irish for "farmer"), *maighstir* (Gaelic for "master"). Doubtless there are other vowels used as well.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question of why *guard* does not have *-er*.